# How to make subdomain routing work if there's conditions that I want to pass first

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I want to make subdomain routing work in laravel when the username in the users table  isn't null and if and if there's a corresponding shortcode on the orders if the shortcode there is abcdf and the username is johndoe, i want to be redirected to the

> abcdf.appname.test/johndoe

table if not then just go to the

> web_app.name.test/normaluser/

This was already my regular setup

```
Route::group([
    'namespace' => 'Standard',
    'middleware' => 'isStandardUser',
    'prefix' => 'normaluser'
], function () {
```

Comment: This would be a good case for a [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware). Did you try anything?

Comment: This is just my middleware code bro @Mozammil ,https://pastebin.com/UwkUTLS6  somewhat like that lol : ) But yeah you're right this is a good use case for it.. but w/regards to like hte subdomain routing, have u implemented it b4 ? is it easy ? cause I haven't yet .

Comment: No, but I am sure it shouldn't be that difficult. Basically, your middleware would check if it satisfies a certain condition and do the redirects.